# Chunks of different sizes on large timeseries dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I need to import a large dataset into pandas dataframe in order to make some data manipulations.

I found out that a good way to do that would be:

- Use chunking to load in and process dataframes in chunks.Breaking a task down, processing the different parts separately, and combining them later on.

If I define my chuncksize equals 1000:

```
pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=engine, chunksize=1000)
```

Each iteration of the loop reads 1000 rows into a dataframe.

However, my dataframe has a DATE column, and I need to be sure that every chunk contains the entire time-series(DATE Column) of each the product (SKU column).

```
  DATE     STORE   COD  SKU  UNITS_SOLD
2018-02-01  HD01    CD  70  539.000
2018-03-01  HD01    CD  70  511.000
2018-04-01  HD01    CD  70  468.000
2018-05-01  HD01    CD  70  447.000
2018-06-01  HD01    CD  70  382.000
2018-07-01  HD01    CD  70  348.000
2018-02-01  HA01    CD  80  539.000
2018-03-01  HA01    CD  80  511.000
2018-04-01  HA01    CD  80  468.000
2018-05-01  HA01    CD  80  447.000
2018-06-01  HA01    CD  80  382.000
2018-07-01  HA01    CD  80  348.000
```

What is the best way to make sure each chunk will return the entire product history?
If there is a product on this 1000 rows that is not complete, I want to avoid split into 2 chunks.

Comment: can you clarify your *entire product history/entire time-series/product that is not complete* ?

Comment: I think one option could be, save the rows of incomplete product to be prepended on next  chunk

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest,
In order to perform some manipulations, I need to groupby products by Date. I can't do this if I have the same product in 2 differents chuncks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with timeseries I don't think that using chunks it's a right approach. You should use groupby and then apply the analysis you like. in pandas/dask is basically the same. Let's say you want just to have the number of store for every sku

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = dd.read_csv("file.csv") 
out = df.groupby('SKU')["STORE"].nunique().compute()
```

Comment: Hi @rpanai, thanks for your answer. Supposing this csv file has 30gb - if I use this approach, it will perform without using too much memory ?

Comment: You should give a try. I could try to make an experiment over the we. It's the analysis that you are planning to do one-off or you'll need to run every day/week/ month? In the second case it's worth considering the way the analysis work and have the partition your data accordingly. If you have any doubt contact me.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use groupby in the SQL being sent, meaning that you will need to loop over all the possible values of SKU. It is possible that you could use chunking, if you fist set up a view in the server side which explicitly orders the data this way.